# npm update my project no working

Tags: npm

I want to update my project and run `npm update`
but nothing updated.

Why the Wanted is `0.55.5` not `0.56.3` ?
Why nothing updated ?

npm: 5.6.0

`$ npm outdated
Package  Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
rollup    0.55.5  0.55.5  0.56.3  rollup-starter-code-splitting`

package.json
`json
{
  "name": "rollup-starter-code-splitting",
  "devDependencies": {
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.2",
    "rollup": "^0.55.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "serve": "^6.4.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "watch": "rollup -c -w",
    "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel start watch",
    "start": "serve public"
  }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [npm doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json):

- **~version** "Approximately equivalent to version"
- **^version** "Compatible with version"

And from [npm update](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update):

If app's package.json contains:

```
"dependencies": {
  "dep1": "^1.1.1"
}
```

Then npm update will install dep1@1.2.2, because 1.2.2 is latest and 1.2.2 satisfies ^1.1.1.

Tilde Dependencies
However, if app's package.json contains:

```
"dependencies": {
  "dep1": "~1.1.1"
}
```

In this case, running npm update will install dep1@1.1.2. Even though the latest tag points to 1.2.2, this version does not satisfy ~1.1.1, which is equivalent to >=1.1.1 <1.2.0. So the highest-sorting version that satisfies ~1.1.1 is used, which is 1.1.2.

Thus, I think 0.56.3 is not compatible with 0.55.3. Yo need to modify your package.json to the latest version:

```
"rollup": "^0.56.3"
```

Comment: but 0.56.3 satisfies ^0.55.3.  isn't it?

Comment: I see, because Caret Dependencies below 1.0.0, right?

Comment: Caret Ranges ^1.2.3 ^0.2.5 ^0.0.4
Allows changes that do not modify the left-most non-zero digit in the [major, minor, patch] tuple

Comment: Yes @zunyite, caret ranges are the reason.